# mail codeigniter was sent,but not found in inbox

Tags: codeigniter, email

i was testing to send email by using codeigniter and i successfully send the email,but when i checked my inbox,i didn't find my email i send before.

here's controller:

```
 $this->load->library('email');
  $this->email->from('email@yahoo.com', 'my name');
$this->email->to('email@yahoo.com'); 
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
 $this->email->message('Testing the email class.'); 
$this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

success message:

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail


  From: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
  Return-Path: 
  Reply-To: "XXXXXXX@yahoo.com" 
 X-Sender: XXXXXXX@yahoo.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <XXXXXXX@yahoo.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Email_Test?=
Testing the email class.
```

Answer (score 2):

You may check your Spam folder in your email account.
Sometimes gmail/yahoo set email as spam when the mail send from local server.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following config...

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'your host',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'your email address',
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'mailpath' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE;
    ); 
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server, you should also check your mail server logs to see if the email actually made it off the box.  Sometimes you might have success sending it, as the mail is passed to EXIM on your server, but the mail might die in a queue.

If this is a linux box, typically start looking in `/var/log/exim4/` etc; (of course depends on your mail server setup).

Comment: windows,i'm using localhost